# Spying on abstract method (Sinon + TS)

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, sinon

Given the following class, how can I spy on the abstract method `f` and make sure it is being called in other implemented methods (`g`)? I'm using Sinon + TypeScript. Using `sinon.stub` or `sinon.spy` does not work because the class does not really have a member of that name.

```
class MyClass {
   abstract f(): number;
   g(): void {
     //some logic
     f();
   }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's the test result?